# Are arrays primitives in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I thought the term primitive was used for data types in C++, but when I search up on Google if arrays are primitives in C++, the first popular result says arrays are primitives in C++. I know arrays are built in C++, but I have never heard the term of primitive being used for array in C++. Is the term primitive able to be used on data structures as well, instead of just data types? How are arrays primitives sin C++.

Here is the link: [http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs1410/textbook/7.Arrays/cpp_v_java.html](http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/%7Edab/cs1410/textbook/7.Arrays/cpp_v_java.html)

Comment: I don't know that you're going to get a straight answer. "Primitive type" is not an official piece of C++ terminology even if it is popular in conversation.

Comment: “is a primitive, unstructured data type” - ‘primitive’ is used as an adjective there, not a category. Also, since Java has a strong definition of ‘primitive’ per the _Java_ specification, might not want to use a comparison article to learn about or attempt to justify C++ type categorizations..

Comment: Also in C++ you have two distinct *types* of an array, (1) a typical array of fundamental types, `char`, `short`, `int`, etc... or of any object and (2) the STL array container. See [Array declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) and [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: "Primitive" is a Java-ism for non-object types (which, from memory, are `int`, `byte`, `short`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`, and `char`). In the link, it means that a C++ array is not an object in the Java sense - in Java, an array is essentially an instance of an unnamed class with members like length (number of elements) but, in C++, an array is a collection of elements, not contained within any data structure. The terminology is also - intentionally or otherwise - disparaging of C++ - an approach used in "comparisons" of programming languages by people who prefer one over the other

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. C++ has built-in C-style arrays, which are problematic for many reasons, including that they don’t have a known size, they decay to a pointer, etc. So yes, C++ has built-in arrays in the language. Furthermore, the C++ standard library has several array-like containers. Typically you want to use these: we are writing C++ not C after all. So if you want a fixed-size array (size known at compile time) consider `std::array` of you don’t know the size up front, choose `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ at its core is base language which allows for creating integral types, pointers, static arrays, classes, enums, etc. You can create static vectors such as char array[32], but these obviously cannot be resized easily and make bugs more prone. It's essentially C with a *whole ton* of extra language features. (side note: don't be fooled, they *are* different languages. You can easily tell when someone has written C++ code, when they are a C or Java programmer).

C++ is actually a *standard*, which means multiple organisation will implement the C++ standard in their own way. C++ does *not* want and should not be responsible for implementing every language feature that every user wants, as this makes the standard bloated and too hard to maintain for all vendors. There are too many people using the language for too many different, specialised things that it's not possible to make everyone happy.

What C++ has done though, is to create general-purpose libraries *on-top* of the base C++ language which makes things such as dynamic-arrays (vectors), managed pointers(shared_pointers), and other common features available to the user. This library is known as the STL, and for most users, is used in almost every piece of code they write. Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/ for more information on the STL. To answer your confusion, these are *almost* primitive types due to always being used, but strictly speaking, primitive types are only built into the language.

If someone is coding for a high-performance game, then they may *not* use the STL as it could be too slow. They may use a completely different library which is faster. Smaller size on disk or anything else they desire. That's the beauty of C++ - you can pick and choose anything you want, so C++ works for you, not against you, no matter the industry you are in and no matter what your needs are.

As a foot note: To add more confusion to the mix, C++, like many other languages has been evolving. The version of C++ you are using is the year number, ie: C++03, C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20, etc etc. Each one of these versions added more features to both the base c++ language and to the STL. So when coding, make sure the compiler you are using supports the features you want. I'd suggest C++11 at a bare minimum these days.